# Blurring effect disappeared on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, blur, ios7.1

For some reason the blur effect is gone from my app on iOS 7.1. I'm running the same code on a device with iOS 7.0.x and on another with 7.1. Here's what I see:

**iOS 7.0.x**
[image: iOS 7.0.x]

**iOS 7.1**
[image: iOS 7.1]

What can be the issue and how to fix this? (obviously I want to keep the blur effect :))

UPDATE:

This is the color I set:

```
    [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f
                       green:201.0f/255.0f
                        blue:0.0f/255.0f
                       alpha:1.0];
```

and I set it from the `barTintColor` property

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to consolidating the translucency of the navigation bar between iPhone 5S and 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436450/how-to-consolidating-the-translucency-of-the-navigation-bar-between-iphone-5s-an)

Comment: Maybe you could show this *same code* you run ?

Comment: @AncAinu edited post with code used

Comment: @jervine10 well that post doesn't really have an answer. It has a cause. My question is how do I get the blur effect back on 7.1

Comment: @SergeyCatraniuc did you try my solution ?

Comment: the blurring effect appears on `armv7s` or `arm64` (or newest I'd guess) architectures only in iOS7.1+. on the rest of the architectures it is just a semi-transparent view.

Comment: @holex yes, I'm well aware of that. As written in a previous comment I'm using a 5c and 5s phones, which should support the blurring

Comment: From my tests, the only way to have some sort of translucent navigation bar with the native SDK (i.e. w/o FXBlurView and the like), is to use UIBarStyleBlack with translucent = YES -> all other settings simply result in barely visible blurring effect. Still waiting for someone (or Apple) to solve this issue.

Comment: Just wanted to add that with my proposed configuration, you can have a faint tint using backgroundColor with alpha<1. For apps that already use a dark theme, it might be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the second screenshot is taken from an iPhone 4 ?
On the iPhone 4 and iPad 2 blur effect is replaced with a simply sample color with transparency.

Comment: Apple made changes to blur effect in iOS 7.1. Upgrade the iPhone 5C to iOS 7.1.

Comment: well, that doesn't really fix my problem. I want to get the blur working on 7.1

Comment: try to set an `alpha < 1` to the color

Comment: didn't try that, hold on

Answer (score 2):

By the way, it's worth noting that the image that you describe as having no blurring/translucency actually does. If you take that snapshot and pump up the contrast, you can see that there actually is something going on in the background. Here is your original "no blurring/translucency image", which I bumped up contrast in Photoshop:

[image: high contrast]

It's barely visible to the naked eye unless you manipulate the image, but the blurring/translucency is actually there.

Comment: I agree. I think they just scaled back the translucency-blurring a little. Rightly so in my opinion. :)

Comment: yeah, I've noticed that it's not completely solid. I've also tried your solution and it doesn't work on my 5s with 7.1 installed. Actually changing the alpha doesn't make any difference at all :(

Comment: what device and iOS version did you use to take those screenshots?

Comment: My bad. On 7.1 device, the `alpha` setting has no effect. I've removed that from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Settings > General > Increase Contrast > Reduce Transparency` is probably enabled on the 7.1 device.

Answer (score 0):

**At a glance**

It seems the navigation bar simply doesn't have anymore blur effet since iOS7.1. At least I ran many tests, by doing new app sample, it doesn't have anymore.

**Workaround (work on iOS 7.1)**

[Here a sample](http://dl.free.fr/tvgRecyOR) using [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)

It's not marvelous but it works fine and it's customizable. My example is certainly not the best.

**Previous solution proposed (doesn't work on iOS7.1)**

Here is my solution to find back a similar effect. It is ok for release it doesn't use private API. But it can have issue with next update of iOS since it rely on inside structure of `UINavigationBar`.

Simply do that in your `viewDidLoad` or where ever you want since it works :

```
// First we make the background's navigation bar totally translucent
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor clearColor]] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Then we create UIToolBar, which are still using blur effect
UIToolbar *tab = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
// We add it the barTintColor we want, works the same as since iOS 7.0.3, don't forget alpha value
tab.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.2];

// And finally we add it to the background view of UINavigationBar... but it can change with future release of iOS. Be aware !
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews firstObject] addSubview:tab];
```

I also *advice you to use **AutoLayout*** to constraint the `UIToolBar` to be always the size of it's parent, for rotations etc... I didn't do it to let the code short and simple.

Hope it helps you guys !

Comment: Hey Anc, thanks for the tip, I'll have to try it a bit later. But it's a bit too hackie for my taste. Even if it does work, I won't end up using it (not really worth it :)). But if it works I'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: I guess you won't have any other option than mine (or even more tricky ones)

Comment: Not possible, I did try it before write it here. You can try in a new project (simple view one) you will see it works. Then you can find what's the difference with your app.

Comment: did you try it on 7.1?

Comment: Mistake of mine, I ended up confusing devices

Comment: no problem. but I'm starting to believe that there's really no way to affect the blur starting with 7.1. what a shame :(

Comment: @SergeyCatraniuc I edited my answer proposing a new solution which work, for what it worth.