# UINavigationBar blur iOS 7.1 and above

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationbar, ios7.1

How to have navigation bar blurred like on the first image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436450/how-to-consolidating-the-translucency-of-the-navigation-bar-between-iphone-5s-an). I did some research, but seems tint color and translucent does not apply for this needs. I am using iOS 7 and iOS 8

The problem that I have table under navigation bar and it change content dynamically, so the blur effect should be changed as well each time I scroll table.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055740/how-can-i-produce-an-effect-similar-to-the-ios-7-blur-view

Comment: @Aaron I am not sure if it will work if I will scroll up table and content under navigation bar will be changed

Comment: Have you tried any of these solutions?

Comment: @Aaron, thank you for suggestion, but as you see on the link I've added here are two navigation bars and top has beautiful blur effect. On the link you provide here are one dynamic solution that only works for iOS7. Other we can use for create static blurred image using current graphic context.

Comment: The link I provided has a half dozen possible solutions. Are you saying that none of them will work for both iOS 7 and iOS 8? What about this custom `UIView`: https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView referenced in the link I provided?

Comment: @Aaron seems like good solution that works for me. One thing that I need to adjust frame of that view and make it (0, -20, navigationBar.width, navigationBar.height + 20). But works for me. Thanks