# How to change only text color when UISegmentedControl value changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using `UISegmentedControl` in my app and i could able to toggle the text color when it changes the state. But by default selected segment contains a different tint color like below image

[image]

I do not want to have different tint color when it is in selected state. I just wish to differentiate the selected segment only by the text color like below image.

[image]

I know this is a silly question but none of the other similar questions provide me a proper answer.

Can you anyone please guide me to achieve this?

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest not doing this.

You realise that this just makes it harder to use right? For a colour blind person (about 1 in 11 men are colourblind) your version is pretty much impossible to use. For people with poor sight it's very hard to use. The best test for usability (and advice from Apple engineers) is to turn it into greyscale images and see if you can still use it.

For example...

**Section tint**

[image]

becomes...

[image]

Using a contrasting colour text on the selected index would improve this.

**Your colour scheme**

[image]

becomes...

[image]

This is very hard to determine which section is selected.

Answer (score 1):

This is enough.

```
 NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17], UITextAttributeFont,
                                    [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                    nil];
        [_segment setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSDictionary *highlightedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
        [_segment setTitleTextAttributes:highlightedAttributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If you want to change the color when the segment change

```
- (IBAction)horseSegmentChanged:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {

        if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {


            NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17], UITextAttributeFont,
                                        [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                        nil];
            [_segment setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSDictionary *highlightedAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
            [_segment setTitleTextAttributes:highlightedAttributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        } else if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) { // selected shared blogs



        }


     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think this will work for me. Please read the question again "i could able to toggle the text color when it changes the state". My requirement is to change the background color(tint color) of the selected segment if you notice first image you can see two different color(white and grey) i just don't want these two colors. I just want only one color(look at second image) even if it is selected.

Comment: I don't have any issue in changing textcolor

Answer (score 0):

Find the below customsegment control

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CustomSegmentControl : UISegmentedControl

@end

#import "CustomSegmentControl.h"
@interface CustomSegmentControl ()
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color;

@end
@implementation CustomSegmentControl

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

@end
```

This will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Fogmeister that this is probably not a very good idea in terms of usability. That said, UISegmentedControl allows you to set a background image for a specific state. You could set an image with the same color for each of the UISegmentedControl states, and that would give you the effect you desire.

To programmatically create an image from UIColor, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496441/creating-a-uiimage-from-a-uicolor-to-use-as-a-background-image-for-uibutton).

And some sample code for a segmented control with an always white background (considering an UIImage category as the one referenced above):

```
[self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```