# tableview header moves down when reloading. Swift -iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, storyboard

I am using a Tabbarcontroller with navigation bar.
There are two ViewControllers in the Tabbarcontroller.
There is a search bar and below it i display a table.
This table is grouped normally. It displays date based grouped customCellA, and the date is my header.
When searching I clear the header height (to zero) and and display a single section. This section contains search result displayed in customCellB.

All the above ui have been created in storyboard

When I switch between tabbars and come back to this viewController. The gap between the search bar (which includes header) and the first cell group seems to increase.

I tried different options like (mostly in viewwillappear)

- Calling reloadData() twice
- calling tableView.layoutSubviews()
- automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
- contentOffset
- edgesForExtendedLayout

Should i use them in viewdidlayoutsubviews...?

I Used folllowin links

- [Swift ios 9: Section header change position after reload data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206807/swift-ios-9-section-header-change-position-after-reload-data)
- [iOS 7 Custom TableView Is Under TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173630/ios-7-custom-tableview-is-under-tabbar)
- [Swift: Tableview scrolls under navigation bar but over status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392421/swift-tableview-scrolls-under-navigation-bar-but-over-status-bar)
- and more

Nothing seems to work. I am not sure where i am going wrong.
I am using swift3 and xcode 8.3.X

I am unable to show the error here as its official project.
Please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: Are you adding Constraints Programatically for tableView or modifying any constraint in code

Answer (score 0):

What I did for my project was just make the table view top constraint flush against the top of the whole screen, above the navigation bar.

Comment: I did that.. i connected the table view top constraint connect to top of the whole view (ViewController top). Dint work.

Comment: Normally fist time loading the ViewConroller with the table view. It works fine. This issue of header moving down happens only when switching between tabs. If i go the second tab and come back to the first tab (which contains the able view) header seems to go down. I doubt if its and issue with the constraints or issue with parent view.