# Set BackgroundColor of Second View and Supplementary View of UISplitViewController

Tags: background-color, uisplitviewcontroller

As you can see, in a 3 lines SplitViewController, on the top, there are while space that are not match the background color.

Any way to set them the same as the blue background?

[image]

[image]

The red background color was set by self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red. But set color there can't match the background color.

Answer (score 0):

At last I have to create an image from color and set the image as background.

Thanks to this post.

[Creating a UIImage from a UIColor to use as a background image for UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496441/creating-a-uiimage-from-a-uicolor-to-use-as-a-background-image-for-uibutton)

```swift
extension UIImage {
    static func from(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }
}
```

```swift
if let nav = self.navigationController {
    nav.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.from(color: UIColor(named: "Blue")!), for: .default)
}
```